# Encontrar valores de input com mesma classe

Tags: jquery

Como posso agir para somar os valores dos inputs de mesma classe sendo que, o número de inputs não tem um padrão, ou seja, pode ser que hora a classe `p1` possua 5 instancias, hora 1.

A estrutura seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<input type='text' class='p1' />
<input type='text' class='p1' />
<input type='text' class='p1' />

<input type='text' class='p2' />
<input type='text' class='p2' />
<input type='text' class='p2' />

<input type='text' class='p3' />
<input type='text' class='p3' />
<input type='text' class='p3' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer um **each** nos elementos correspondentes a classe procurada.

Exemplo:

```
var sum_p1 = 0;
$('.p1').each(function (){
  // O + antes do $ é para converter o valor para inteiro, uma vez que ele retorna string.
  sum_p1 += +$(this).val();
});
```

Pode ainda criar uma função genérica para fazer isso:

```
function sumInputValuesByClass(c){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.'+c).each(function (){
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, está faltando o name que no caso deve ser um array. E o value do input, que pelo que entendi, é o que você quer somar:

```
<input name="p1[]" value="1" type='text' class='p1' />
<input name="p1[]" value="2" type='text' class='p1' />
<input name="p1[]" value="3" type='text' class='p1' />
```

Então você faz a soma em jQuery, que pode ser acionada por qualqure outro action. Aqui segue no load do documento e irá trazer um alert com o número 6, que é a soma dos values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    p = $('.p1');
    soma = 0;
    for(i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
        soma += Number(p[i].value);
    }
    alert(soma);
})
</script>
```